# image_tag points to assets/ in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, hyperlink, tags

I'm migrating Rails app from 2 to 3.

Somehow from,

```
link_to image_tag("icon.png")
```

**img**'s **src** attribute is prefixed with "/**assets**/icon.png" instead of "/**images**/icon.png" as it was in Rails 2.

What is the correct way? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rails 3.1+ was released with a new set of features referred to collectively as the "Asset Pipeline." Read all about it in the [Rails Asset Pipeline documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: Thsnks @zeke, exactly what I needed. Going to read this one. Also,  after a quick play, seems like link_to image_tag("/images/icon.png") also does the job.